# Adding pairs of elements

Tags: arrays, for-loop

So I have a table of numbers/array like here 
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], the indices being A[0] = 1, A[1] = 2 ... A[i=5] = 6 etc.

Now I want to basically take the average of every two elements, such that my resulting array is as follows:

B = [1.5, 3.5, 5.5], where B[0] = (A[0] + A[1])/2, B [1] = (A[2]+A[3])/2, and B[2] = (A[4]+A[5])/2

My code keeps making the mistake of also considering the additions, (A[1] + A[2])/2 and so on etc. to give me the following resulting array,

[1.5, **2.5**, 3.5, **4.5**, 5.5]

I don't need the bolded elements. I am not sure why this is happening but this is what I have:

```
for(i=0; i<=5; i+=1)
    B[i] = (A[i] + A[i+1])/2 
    for(j=i+(i+2); j<=5; j+=1)
       B[j] =  (A[j]+ A[j+1])/2
    endfor
endfor
```

Can anyone tell me what am doing wrong?

Comment: I think that you need to clearly define your output and the formula you want to use regardless of the code. Specially, define B[i]. What do you mean you don't want the bolded numbers? Do you want 1.5,3.5 and 5.5 only in B? The more you say, the easier it is for people to help.

Comment: It is not clear what language is used here. If anyone knows can they tag it correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Use a different increment in your `for` loop:

```
j=0
for (i=0;i<=5;i+=2)
  B[j]=(A[i]+A[i+1])/2
  j+=1
end for
```

and you don't need the second, inner loop.

Comment: I did do so by using i+=2, but it didn't seem to work and gave me the same results?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this more complicated than it is. You need the first 2 values in the array in your calculation, then you need the next 2 values, etc. This only require 1 loop through the array.

Something like this:

```
j = 0 
for(i=0; i<=5; i+=2)
    B[j] = (A[i] + A[i+1])/2 
    j += 1
endfor
```

You might need to check that there actually is an equal amount of values in `A`, otherwise `A[i+1]` might cause an error.